# NavigationStack pushing too many views

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationstack, swift-hashable

Hello I am fairly new to swiftui and I am creating a NavigationStack from an array of items. Every item in the array is pushed into navigation when I click on the item (I have to click the back button many times to get back to the root) I can't seem to find out why it is doing this.

Main view...

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var BiasStruct: BiasData = BiasData.allBias
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack{
            NavigationStack{
                List{
                    ForEach(BiasStruct.biases, id: \.self){ entry in
                        NavigationLink(value: entry){
                            Text("\(entry.name)")
                        }
                        
                    }
                    .navigationTitle("Biases")
                    .navigationDestination(for: Biase.self){ bias in
                        Text("\(bias.name)")
                    .searchable(text: $searchText)
                    }
                    
                }
                
            }
            .padding(8)
        }
    }
}
```

Bias struct...

```
struct BiasData: Codable, Hashable {
    var biases: [Biase]
    static let allBias: BiasData = Bundle.main.decode(file: "sample2.json")
}


struct Biase: Codable, Hashable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var related, tags, quote, question: [String]
    var description, overcome : String
    var resourceName, resource: [String]
    var example: [String]
    var isFaved: Bool? = false
    
    
    //I created this to set isFaved to false
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.id = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
        self.name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        self.related = try container.decode([String].self, forKey: .related)
        self.tags = try container.decode([String].self, forKey: .tags)
        self.quote = try container.decode([String].self, forKey: .quote)
        self.description = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .description)
        self.question = try container.decode([String].self, forKey: .question)
        self.overcome = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .overcome)
        self.resourceName = try container.decode([String].self, forKey: .resourceName)
        self.resource = try container.decode([String].self, forKey: .resource)
        self.example = try container.decode([String].self, forKey: .example)
        self.isFaved = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because

```
.navigationTitle("Biases")
.navigationDestination(for: Biase.self){ bias in
    Text("\(bias.name)")
}
```

Should be defined for **`List`**, not for `ForEach`:

```
NavigationStack{
    List{
        ForEach(BiasStruct.biases
        }
        // <-- NOT HERE
    } // <-- HERE instead
    .navigationTitle("Biases")
    .navigationDestination(for: Biase.self){ bias in
        Text("\(bias.name)")
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I removed the .searchable() after the the ForEach loop and it worked

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).